# How do I parse xml response in JSON in GAS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, api, xml-to-json

I am trying to get data via external API but it comes in XML. I would like to convert it to JSON before using it on another function. Anyone with an idea on how to do this, kindly help. Here is my code.

```
function getData() { 

 var options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ak
    }
};  
var url = 'https://data.purelyhr.com/daily?ak='+ ak + '&sDate=' + start + '&eDate=' + end + '&TimeOffTypeName';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); 
var response = xmlToJSON.parseString(response);

Logger.log(response)
}
```

Comment: Does the api provide json data?

Comment: @TheMaster, It does not..only XML